# how to guide tkdiff on matching lines

Tags: diff

I'm using `tkdiff` on 2 big files that might have some sections that are very different. However, through these 2 files there are several points (known in advanced) that are exactly the same.

`tkdiff` gets lost, and after some good comparison, the rest is useless.

How can I tell `tkdiff` that line x in file X match line y in file Y, so it will be like an anchor that the diff should be around it?

I know I can split the file to smaller files according to these anchors, but I'll end up with dozens of files needed to be diff.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. It would be good if you added an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

tkdiff has no feature to allow you to do that. However, tkdiff just runs diff to get the results. You can configure tkdiff to run a different diff program, so perhaps you can write a shell script that can filter the results before giving it back to tkdiff. As long as the program returns data in the proper format, tkdiff will display it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [answer (strictly line by line diff)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136380/compare-two-files-strictly-line-by-line-without-insertions-or-deletions)

Say, you can generate two temp files by using `nl` and compare them using `tkdiff`:

```
nl file1 > file1_nl
nl file2 > file2_nl
tkdiff file1_nl file2_nl
```

One-line version is:

```
nl file1 > file1_nl; nl file2 > file2_nl; tkdiff file1_nl file2_nl
```

The suggested solution in that answer somehow does not give me highlight in `tkdiff`:

```
tkdiff <(nl file1) <(nl file2)
```